# Best basis selection problem with inequalities solution methods

Tags: optimization

I'm solving an optimization problem in form

$\min \sum x$

subject to,

$ A x = b$  (1)

$ g  x \leq d$ (2)

$ x \geq 0$ (3)

Optimization variable is x. The number of rows of A is considerably higher than the number of columns, i.e., the system $Ax = b$ is overdetermined. In equation 2, g and d repesent a nonegative vectors with the proper dimension.

My goal is to find a sparse solution of the problem. I want to find a solution with minimal number of nonzero elements.

Solving the optimization problem only under (1) represents a best basis selection problem that has been solved in literature [link](https://scholar.google.cz/scholar?q=best%20basis%20selection&hl=cs&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ved=0CB0QgQMwAGoVChMI2pD6npu1xwIVBsMUCh0J3g8p).

But what if we add additional constraints (2) and (3), are the any efficient methods to solve the best basis selection problem with (1), (2), and (3)?